# Why Easymock throws error for a nicemock?

Tags: easymock, illegalstateexception

I have mocked out HttpServletRequest, a service in my test:

```
request = createNiceMock(HttpServletRequest.class);
service = createStrictMock(DataProviderService.class);
```

I am verifying behaviour that my controller handles exception thrown by service, by setting expectaion:

```
expect(service.getData(someObject)).andThrow(new MyException());
replay(endPoint);
```

I verify the same as:

```
ModelAndView mav = controller.provideDefaultScreen(request);
verify(service);
```

My controller invokes service and in case of exception, sets exception details in request

```
request.setAttribute("exceptionMessage", e.getMessage());
```

This line is throwing out an error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: missing behavior definition for the preceding method call:
HttpServletRequest.getAttribute("someAttributeCheckedEarlier")
Usage is: expect(a.foo()).andXXX()
```

I am least bothered about what my controller does to request, I am only concerned that it should eat up the exception thrown by service. Correspondingly, I've created request as nick mock. Why do I still get this error?

Answer (score 3):

Unless you have cut it from your snippets of code, you don't seem to have called `replay` on the NiceMock. This will move it out of the "record" mode and make it usable.

Comment: To be more specific, you need replay(request, service); for your example. You actually do have replay(endPoint), which is not declared in your example here. Please check whether this is wrong only in this example or your actual coding as well (might have easily happened after a manual refactoring).

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the above answer, have you considered using [Spring Mock](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/mock/web/package-summary.html)? It has nice support for mocking and provides a host of classes that would not required using easymock atleast for supporting out of web container testing.

This framework can be used independent of Spring and your application doesn't need to use Spring Framework. Here is a [nice article](http://www.devx.com/Java/Article/30067) too...

Hope that helps.